# How can I reverse engineer an old MMO?

Tags: multiplayer, mmo, client-server

I want to revive an old MMO.

Only the old client exists from the game, so I would have to write a whole server for it.

I'm not sure how to start editing things in the already made client. Most likely I will need catch requests and somehow change those to my own.

How do I go about actually working/editing that client? What should I use, having only .dlls on some other already compiled files?

Comment: You could probably do the "revival" without editing the client. Check whether the network protocol of the game has been documented on the internet first

Comment: You don't just need to find out what the messages sent by the client mean. That's the easy part. The real problem is finding out what it expects in return. Sorry to curb your enthusiasm, but without a reference server implementation available, this is likely a hopeless endeavor. You would have an easier time to implement the game from scratch.